# How do the flight decks work in unison on the Stratolaunch?

Tags: aircraft-design, stratolaunch

[This article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-5633239/Stratolaunch-biggest-plane-built-MONTHS.html) implies that the Stratolaunch has two flight decks. How are the dual flight decks arranged on the [Stratolaunch aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratolaunch_Systems)?

- I'm curious if things are fly by wire or if there are separate controls?
- Are the flight decks both fully operational and mirror images of each other?
- If there are duplicate switches and controls, how do the counterparts reflect changes initiated from the cross side?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the flight deck is only in one of the two fuselages I am trying to find some info to confirm before posting an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Stratolaunch Systems, there will only be one cockpit as [mentioned here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaled_Composites_Stratolaunch):

> The pilot, co-pilot and flight engineer will be in the right fuselage
>   cockpit, while the left fuselage one is empty and unpressurized.

News can be misleading. [This article's](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-5633239/Stratolaunch-biggest-plane-built-MONTHS.html) title says that each fuselage has its own cockpit but later, it clarifies:

> The left-hand fuselage has what looks like a cockpit with windows to
>   onlookers, but the section is in fact empty and unpressurised.

It does look like there both fuselages have cockpits.

[image]
<sub>*[Image Source](https://www.seattletimes.com/business/boeing-aerospace/allens-colossal-stratolaunch-plane-emerges-from-its-lair/)*</sub>

Comment: That was the exact article that spawned the question. And I obviously was too lazy to finish reading it. ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In stratolaunch, the only the right fuselage houses the flight crew i.e. the cockpit. From [stratolaunch.com](http://www.stratolaunch.com/):

> The right fuselage houses the flight crew and the left fuselage contains flight data systems.

[image: Stratolaunch]

Stratolaunch, image from [bubblemania.fr](http://bubblemania.fr/en/bulle-avion-geant-stratolaunch-le-plus-grand-avion-du-monde-lanceur-de-fusees-1er-vol-dessai-en-2019/); original appears to be from [stratolaunch.com](http://www.stratolaunch.com/)